# Strange behavior: the displaying of vue-multiselect options panel cause a button unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, vue-multiselect

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-33327

Steps to reproduce

1. Clicking the vue-multiselect to display the options panel
2. Choosing several options
3. Clicking the 'Unclickable Submit' button
4. Observing the strange behavior

As we've seen, the 'Unclickable Submit' button is unclickable. It's only clickable when the vue-multiselect lost focus (after the option panels disappear)

Some might said that, the appearance of options panel causing the button 'unclickable', however, the 'Clickable Submit' button is still 'clickable' despite the fact that the options panel is still there.

Others might said that, because the 'Unclickable Submit' button move away from its previous position cause the click event-handler didn't work. That makes sense. However, I also created an Increase Height button, which causes a div to increase its height, to simulate the changing position of the button. In this case, the 'Unclickable Submit' is Clickable..strange!

Another strange thing is the @mousedown event works in the case of the 'Unclickable Submit' button. However, the form didn't submit in this case.

That strange behaviors totally blew my mind. I have no clue what's cause those behaviors. Anyone knows what's happening, please help! Because at the end of the day, I need to make the 'Unclickable Submit' button **Clickable**.

**Update 1**

Another question, why the `@mousedown` event worked but the `@click` event didn't?

**Update 2**

Preventing the button from moving fix the problem, however, is it possible the make the button still clickable despite the fact that it moved away from its previous position?

---

[image]

Comment: It's just a CSS issue because the `blur` event fires before you click and the element moves. You can  verify this by adding `min-height: 70px;` to `.multiselect`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I see your idea, however, that looks like a temporary solution. Because my real project allows users to choose many options at once. Following your solution, looks like I have to set min-height: 300px or some amount around that.

Comment: Not a solution, but an observation. The real fix might be to wrap it in a container with `position: relative` and move the `min-height: 30px` property to that, and make the multi select `position:absolute`

Comment: To answer your update: @click requires a mousedown, and a mouse up. You aren't getting the mouse up because the element shifts on click

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks a lot! Can you turn your comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simpler than I thought it was, all I need is adding this line:

```
@mousedown.prevent
```

to any buttons that were encountering the issue. Althought I don't know exactly what was going on.